# we can not able to Copy Text from Word file to Pdf Directly in Text Box in 11 Pro

Tags: adobe-acrobat

In Adobe 8 Pro we can able to Copy Text from Word file to Pdf Directly in Text Box and it was quite easy. But Now in 11 Pro text from word file copied as Stamp which get complicated. Can you give the solution that text directly past in Text Box.

Comment: What do you mean by "copied as Stamp"?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to paste the text into a notepad window, then copy/paste from there into your PDF. This coverts the data to plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Is the "text box" a fillable field, and active (you can enter text directly)?

If so, make sure that the focus is in the field (the I-beak cursor flashes in the field proper), and paste again.